# Duplicate elements after clicking in a repeater list item

Tags: duplicates, repeater, element, kentico

I've an issue after clicking in repeater list item, I get two items in the detail page instead of one element.

This repeater is for Booking elements and I've added the follow transformation: "Transformation" and "Selected item transformation".

The "Selected item transformation" is applied but I get two elements in the page after apply this transformation.

I tried to add a data list and instead of to get two elements after clicking on an element I get four.

I'm new in Kentico maybe it is a configuration issue.

**Below I detail the configuration for the repeater web part:**

- **Content/Path:**/Events/%
- **Content filter/Page types:** CMS.BookingEvent
- **Content filter/Category name:** {%SiteContext.CurrentCategory.CategoryName#%}

Do you have any idea about what can be the problem?

If you need more information please let me know and I'll send you.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the Design tab, end result and the transformation itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check following below things

1. Does the listed page & detail page uses same page template (is it inherited)?
2. Need to check Selected item transformation, is it setup right?.
3. For testing you can remove category filter and then check.
4. Make sure are you using <%# GetDocumentUrl() %> in list page Transformation

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check list and details pages. In your case details page should inherit template from list page.

Your repeater is responsible for showing list and details, so make sure there is no extra web part (another repeater or any other viewer) that shows details only.

Also try to check Hide on child pages setting in your repeater - this will help you to figure out if repeated renders 2 details (in case no details shows now) or there is another web part for details (in case only one item details appear now).

Answer (score 0):

Does the listed page uses same page template (is it inherited)? Do you have just one repeater on that page?

The selected item transformation renders on target page (detail of listed page) but the page needs to use same page template (or inherit the one that is on parent page listing page)

Alternatively, don't specify selected transformation and make the repeater on target page to display just its properties.

Answer (score 0):

This page is using the selected item transformation correct? And this happens when you are navigating to the event page (/Event/CustomEvent1)?

Does this happen for every event? Does the event page url have any special characters in it? I have had an issue before if the page has an _ in the name and url, it will break the repeater. This was fixed in a hotfix in K9.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still running with this issue, I'd suggest to remove SelectedItemTransformation and display detailed content on specific document i.e. /Event/CustomEvent1. You can use either repeater for read current document only and set detailed Transformation in "Transformation" property itself DON't use "SelectedItemTransformation" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for all the answers, they were pretty useful for me.

The problem was related with the inherited template. In my "Listed page" on template tab I chose the option "Clone template as ad-hoc". I've checked in the detail pages that the template option was in "Inherit from parent".

I realized too that in the root template which I've used in the "Listed page" there were a repeater, then I removed it and the problem was fixed.

Thanks so much again.
Kind regards,
Max